# How to align dynamically sized images to the top of a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an array of image thumbnails for an image gallery I'm building. The images maintain their aspect ratios and are fit within square divs. I want the images to align to the TOP of these parent divs, so there's some visual continuity without creating a border. How can I do this?

I've tried using vertical-align top on both the aspect-parent and aspect-fit divs, but this doesn't work.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgzsoqf2/4/)

And the CSS in question:

```css
.aspect-parent {
   width: 140px;
   height: 140px;
   margin: 2px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: lightgrey;
}

img.aspect-fit {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
    <!--first image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://www.sheknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/wpwzggsfqc9bfz2nlnb5.jpeg">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1999</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/ac/64/74ac64e49653dae6b4e593f688ff12f4.jpg">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1900</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--third image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59ab26c6ff7c50083fca77c3/59ab4fb4cf81e025e872464a/5cf83e726069c90001a2ad5d/1559772921407/sandro_botticelli_-_three_graces_in_primavera_detail.jpg?format=2500w">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1909</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm expecting I need to change something with aspect-fit.

Comment: The reason why you aren't achieving this with your current css is because your images actually take up the whole square space by using height:100%; thing is that the extra space that seems like they're not using is just transparent, therefore you cannot move something thats already taking up the whole space up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object-position:top;` is your friend - add it to your `.aspect-fit` class:

```css
.aspect-parent {
   width: 140px;
   height: 140px;
   margin: 2px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: lightgrey;
}

img.aspect-fit {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   object-fit: contain;
   object-position:top;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
    <!--first image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://www.sheknows.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/wpwzggsfqc9bfz2nlnb5.jpeg">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1999</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/ac/64/74ac64e49653dae6b4e593f688ff12f4.jpg">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1900</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--third image-->
    <div class="aspect-parent">
        <img class="aspect-fit" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59ab26c6ff7c50083fca77c3/59ab4fb4cf81e025e872464a/5cf83e726069c90001a2ad5d/1559772921407/sandro_botticelli_-_three_graces_in_primavera_detail.jpg?format=2500w">
        <div id="thumbCaption">
            <i id="Title">artwork title</i><span>, </span><span id="year">1909</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way, you have quite a few identical `id`s dotted around - these should be unique, use classes instead.

Comment: Thanks, Will. I appreciate the comment about the ``id``s too.